# What is the output type of the sn74lvc1g04?

Tags: open-collector, open-drain

It doesn't seem to clearly say totem-pole, open-collector, open-drain, etc.  I wanted to place a pull-up at the output to guarantee a default state, but I feel like this is a bad decision.

[datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc1g04.pdf)

Comment: As an aside, the "nG" parts work exactly the same as the parts without, but with fewer gates. And "LVC" works similar to "HC" but with different voltage levels as thresholds (plus a few additional features).

Comment: For future reference the "04" suffix" usually indicates a totem-pole inverter as it is derived from the original SN7404.  The equivalent one with open collector is "05". "06" and "07" are also open-collector buffers. These days some types do not follow the historic conventions though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's push-pull output (as would be expected, unless otherwise stated). You can see how push-pull it is from the datasheet:

[image]

At 4.5V supply it can sink or source up to 32mA and (Table 7.5) the maximum/minimum voltages under those conditions will be 0.55V/3.8V. So, it's a little better at sinking current than at sourcing it (<550mV drop sinking 32mA and <700mV drop sourcing 32mA).

Adding a resistor will do nothing under normal operating conditions (chip is powered) but waste power when the output is low.

Answer (score 1):

On the datasheet, under "Recommended Operating Conditions", it lists "High Level Output Current" for various conditions.  When its output is high, an open collector/drain part effectivly is disconnected from its output pin, so has no high level output current.  So this part must have a "totempole" output circuit.

Under "Application Information", the datasheet shows the part driving an LED connected to ground - this won't work with an open collector part.